# Entity Framework Slow First Call IRepository DbContext

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

We are using entity framework 6.1.1 with a DbContext like below and EntityTypeConfiguration to map approximately 400 entities to our DbContext.  We then create an instance of our DbContext and use it to create the object sets for each IRepository entity we use in our service layer.  The problem we are having which I cannot find a solution to is that the first call to the db is taking approximately 18 seconds when we are using Ants profiler.

I have looked into generating the views but I cannot find a way to do that when the DbContext does not contain hard-coded DbSet collections to the entities.  Is there a way to pre-generate the views with our pattern and if so will we see a significant performance improvement?

Or is it time to go down a different path, should we create smaller DbContexts which are for specific areas of the database on logical separations?

```
  public class Context: DbContext
  {
#pragma warning disable
    Type dummyType_SqlProviderServices = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);
#pragma


static Context()
{
  Database.SetInitializer(new ContextatabaseInitializer<Context>());

}

public Context(DbConnection con)
  : base(con, false)
{
}

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(ZincContext).Assembly);      
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}

public class EntityRepository<T> : IEntityRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected IDbSet<T> ObjectSet
    {
      get
      {
        if (_objectSet == null)
        {
          _objectSet = this.DbContext.Set<T>();
        }
        return _objectSet;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use AsNoTracking ?

Comment: We don't no as we make use of entity tracking for updates and lazy loading.  Having said that we could move away from that pattern as I don't like that the entities continue to have a handle to the DB for lazy loading and it would ensure we called the Update method on the repository to reattach the entity.  Would it make a significant performance difference?

Comment: Yes, it would. Entity framework can cause significant performance problem, especially first call takes long time. But you can find a lot of resources about that, e.g. turning off AsNoTracking when you don't need it or somothing like pre-compiled queries etc.

Comment: Hmmmm it seems this is going to be a lot more work that I'd hoped, was naively hoping for a click button to generate views and it would go from 18 seconds to 1 :).  We are making use of tracking all over the application to update entities so this will be a large change.  I assume that there isn't a way to pre generate the views the way we are creating and using the DbContext?

Comment: I don't have experience with generating of the views. We were trying to use EF but then we switched to ADO.NET because of performance. Development is slower but application faster. Try to look also at Dapper.NET. EF is great framework, but you have to deal with performance problems all the time.